# Jsoup Html Android

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

Hi i have need parsing jsoup this code: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SPHUKFC9JgK5GO2HumdYWUjZjSXmU_D2O40cnwk7Df8/pubhtml
I have use this: String url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SPHUKFC9JgK5GO2HumdYWUjZjSXmU_D2O40cnwk7Df8/pubhtml";

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new JsoupListView().execute();

}

// Title AsyncTask
private class JsoupListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Jsoup ListView Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {
            // Connect to the Website URL
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Identify Table Class "worldpopulation"
            for (Element table : doc.select("table[class=waffle]")) {

                // Identify all the table row's(tr)
                for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Identify all the table cell's(td)
                    Elements tds = row.select("td");


                    // Retrive Jsoup Elements
                    // Get the first td
                    map.put("rank", tds.get(0).text());
                    // Get the second td
                    map.put("country", tds.get(1).text());
                    // Get the third td
                    map.put("population", tds.get(2).text());
                    // Get the image src links

                    // Set all extracted Jsoup Elements into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect? Is there an error? In other words: It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: as normal non-android java program i can use your code for accessing the site fine. It seems to work. I conclude it is an Android problem. I added the tag.

Comment: you are aware of the fact that your array ```arraylist``` is local to the ```doInBackground``` method. You do not seem to use it anywhere else. So what do you expect to happen?